# Devise and Facebook Custom Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I am trying to create the user registration views and model on my website but I am having a small issue :

I am using devise and omniauth to get the facebook connect features working and it works,
But I want my facebook users when they sign in the first time to create their password,
That is also working, I redirect them to the filled sign up form and they only have to enter their password. But I want them to go to a second "sign_up form" named /views/registrations/new_facebook.html.erb  where they can only enter their password and I will also add some other information,

I created the correct view and tested it but I have no idea how to create the correct routes to bypass Devise default

```
match '/facebook' => 'registrations#new', :as => 'new_facebook_user_registration'
```

I believe the issue is with match because that's what's not recognised,

If anyone can help me that would be great thanks,

I added my controller code for omniauth :

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def all
user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
if user.persisted?
      flash[:success] = "Welcome back"
          sign_in_and_redirect user
else
  session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
  redirect_to new_facebook_user_registration_url
end
end
alias_method :facebook, :all
```

end

How can I make the redirect_to new_facebook_user_registration_url actually work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 devise_scope :user do 
 match "registrations/new_facebook" => "registrations#new_facebook" 
 end
```

That's the solution I copied in the registrations controller the new method and named it new_facebook and now everything is working as expected !

Answer (score 0):

I think  the issue is that you're not overriding the devise method that redirects to that path. Also according to the devise docs your routes should be set up with a "devise_for" call.

Here's the wiki page describing how to do what you are asking to do, although you may need a bit of custom logic to deal with cases that aren't facebook signups.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

Some example code from that page:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/an/example/path'
  end
end
```

and the one for routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

Comment: In the OmniauthCallbacksController how can I redirect to something else than new_user_registration_url let's say new_facebook_registration_url ? I want to use that redirection in one case in the controller is that possible ?